# Is typing the PPP password in the PPP username a risk?

Tags: passwords, router

I went to my router admin page where first you need to type in the router's admin and password. I am not talking about that. I am talking about PPP account and password (separate from router's username and password). By accident, I typed in in the PPP password where the PPP username field is. Is my router at risk?

Comment: Did you hit "enter"?

Comment: No I did not hit enter.

Comment: Then. no, there is no risk if the password was not submitted.

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no security difference between the username and password fields here.

Comment: I do appreciate the answer but I feel like you did not understand fully what I meant.

Comment: I understand, just want trying to give some background. I simplified my answer.

Comment: @MikeSchem The OP just replied that the form was not submitted, just the password was typed in the field.

Comment: @schroeder I did see that, but since I don't know what they're doing with the form (they could be sending each key as it's typed), I wanted to make the assumption that the data was submitted to the ISP.